# Debug printf functon disable vxWorks 6.9

Tags: embedded, printf, stdout, vxworks

I am running a VxWorks C application that is launched inside a boot-up script. Everything runs fine, except that I don't see the printf debug traces of my software. I want to turn off debugging log(printf) because I am using the same debug port to interface with another module. My data is being lost, and the system is crashing.

Comment: It is your software, so you can just remove or disable the prints, right?

Comment: Avoid mis-tagging your question.  VxWorks is not [embedded-linux], and the generic [rtos] tag makes little sense since whilst VxWorks is an RTOS, your question has little to do with RTOS specifically.  Hover over [embedded-resource] to see its description and you will see that it is entirely irrelevant.  I have changed the tags.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; you are complaining that you cannot see `printf()` output but asking how to disable `printf()` - that seems to be contradictory.  `printf()` outputs to `stdout`; you should be able to specify what `stdout` refers to or even disable it entirely (a NUL device).